# FragmentTransaction have to replace Fragment childview(FrameLayout) after replaced mainFrame

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have total Three `Fragments`

1.BookAppointmentFirstFragment,
2.BookAppointment1 and 
3.ConfirmAppointment

I did `Fragmenttransaction` from `MainFrag`(Appointments) to First Fragment(i.e `BookAPpointmentFirst`) by replace by "appointment_frame".Like this

```
FragmentManager fm=mContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
BookAppointmentFirstFragment bookAppointmentFirstFragment=new BookAppointmentFirstFragment();

ft.replace(R.id.appointment_frame, bookAppointmentFirstFragment);
ft.addToBackStack(Constants.FRAG_TAG_APPOINTMENTS3);

ft.commit();
```

And from First `Fragment`(i.e `BookAppointmentfirst`) I did transaction to second(i.e Bookappointment1) by replace by "contentmain_home" like this.

```
BookAppointment1 bookAppointment1 = new BookAppointment1();
FragmentManager fragMgnr = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragtrans;
fragtrans = fragMgnr.beginTransaction();
fragtrans.replace(R.id.content_mainhome, bookAppointment1);

fragtrans.addToBackStack(Constants.FRAG_TAG_APPOINTMENTSBOOK1);

fragtrans.commit();
```

After the above I trying to do transaction to `ConfirmFrgment` from Bookappointment1 by replace by appointment_frame but i am getting crash hereno view found "appointment_main". Please help me how I can do this flow.

```
FragmentManager fragMgnr = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragtrans;
fragtrans = fragMgnr.beginTransaction();
fragtrans.replace(R.id.appointment_frame, confirmAppointment);
fragtrans.addToBackStack(Constants.FRAG_TAG_APPOINTMENTSBOOK2);
fragtrans.commit();
```

Above transaction I getting crash no view found "appointment_frame"

Comment: You want get fragment transaction in same frame or another?

Comment: another frame (i.e appointment_frame)

Comment: But onclick event fragment is in contentmain_frame from this fragmentI  am trying to do transaction to Another fragment    I  want this fragment is in appointment_frame

Answer (score 0):

You are getting crash because **appointment_frame** view is not present in **BookAppointment1** Fragment's **layout**, I think **appointment_frame** view is present in your **parent** **activity**

so you need to call like this inside fragment

```
FragmentManager fragMgnr = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragtrans;
fragtrans = fragMgnr.beginTransaction();
fragtrans.replace(R.id.appointment_frame, confirmAppointment);
fragtrans.addToBackStack(Constants.FRAG_TAG_APPOINTMENTSBOOK2);
fragtrans.commit();
```

Comment: I tried your solution but not working, appointment_frame is inside AppointmentMainFragment for this parent is MainActivity.And BookAppointment  replaced with mainframe(Mainactivity layout), now problem is I tried to replace AppointmentMainLayout with confirmAppointment  this transaction is  inside BookAppointment1 . Please help me

Comment: @BharathiSomala Sorry! I am not getting but let you know one thing if you are replacing a fragment from inside fragment and your container is in Activity than you should use getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() ok.

Comment: If you are replacing fragment from inside fragment and container is in inside of Fragment then try to use getChildFragmentManager().